# wrapper or high level class for curl

Tags: php, curl

is any class that allow to call for example method post (url, params) without creating low-level code like curl_init and other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some options:

- [HTTP](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.http.php) (PECL) / requires libcurl
- [HTTP](http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP/docs) (PEAR) / does not use cURL but fsockopen
- [Zend_HTTP](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.http.html) / has multiple adapters, incl. cURL

Answer (score 4):

if you want something very basic and simple 
you can look at links :

http://www.roscripts.com/snippets/show/131

http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3547-PHP-Submit-HTTP-requests-with-the-CURL-extension.html

also look on this SO post

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3045833/recommend-a-curl-wrapper-class-in-php

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at [Snoopy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/snoopy/).

Answer (score 0):

I've used the [cURL wrapper](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/1988-PHP-cURL-extension-wrapper-access-remote-Web-resources.html). It's OO and supports most (all?) of the standard curl methods.